# How can I create a a thread with Veins functionalities?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm trying to create a new thread in my Veins simulation that can use the `Veins::TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle*`, however I'm not able to achieve this goal.

I use a class EVData that should be able to use the functionality, however it gives an error in SUMO about not implemented commands.

Here is the class that has access to the `Veins::TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle*`:

```
class EVData : public BaseWaveApplLayer
{
    public:
        simtime_t lastDroveAt;
        bool sentMessage;
        TraCIMobility::Statistics statistics;
        simtime_t stoppedAt, startedAt, lastUpdate;
        bool isOver;
        void printSomething()
        {
            std::cout<< "data que eu quero: " << traciVehicle->getLaneId() << "\n";
        }

};
```

and here is the thread code:

```
void socketThread(EVData* evD/*, Veins::TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle* tv*/)
{
    std::cout << "sou uma thread nova \n";
    while(!evD->isOver)
    {
        //std::cout << "";
         evD->printSomething();
    }
}
```

The threading works so I have no clue how to solve this issue, can anyone help me?

Comment: Most likely, your code is wrong. You can try running your program on Linux using a memory access debugger like `valgrind` or you can try running your source code through a static code analysis tool like clang's `scan-build`.

Comment: As a second comment, if you are really using multiple threads of execution in your simulation (rather than merely simulating a multi-threaded system), I can only warn against attempting to so without good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! :) Do you have any idea on how to access the traciVehicle through a new thread, created from the one that has access to it?
Regarding your comment, I need to use external software to create new communications, so I need sockets and a thread that is constantly listening for those messages

Comment: @ChristophSommer, I don't know how SO works, so forgive me if you received the notification and I'm tagging you again